# JavaScript recursive function to transform parent/child records into a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-ui

I have a Json array, which is structured perfectly for a Kendo treelist widget (i.e. very simple treelist example [treelist](http://plnkr.co/edit/F84BO3IarTDGh5Cumxl6?p=preview)); however, I now need to render the same data in a Kendo treemap widget.

So, the source data is flat and contains both an `id` and `parentId` field. I now need to recursively visit each node and transform this into a nested array.

I've started a plunk which contains the flat source data (filename is "sourcedata.json"), as well as sample target data ("treedata.json") which currently renders a Kendo treemap if you run the plunk.

```
 http://plnkr.co/edit/Cmfk8YWdm0uPrdDiJIfC?p=preview
```

[treemap data](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cmfk8YWdm0uPrdDiJIfC?p=preview)

Here's the source (fyi: "parentId": null is my root node) -

```js
[
 {
     "id": 0,
     "parentId": 6,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "London",
     "field2": 5546919.064936     
 },
 {
     "id": 1,
     "parentId": 7,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "New York",
     "field2": 2297941.24812     
 },
 {
     "id": 2,
     "parentId": 5,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "Dubai",
     "field2": 9832458.096596     
 },
 {
     "id": 3,
     "parentId": 6,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "Paris",
     "field2": 22700818.88167     
 },
 {
     "id": 4,
     "parentId": 8,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "Stockholm",
     "field2": 3742748.296602,
    
 },
 {
     "id": 5,
     "parentId": 9,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "Middle East",
     "field2": 9832458.096596,
   
 },
 {
     "id": 6,
     "parentId": 9,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "Europe",
     "field2": 31990486.243208,

 },
 {
     "id": 7,
     "parentId": 9,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "NorthAmerica",
     "field2": 2297941.24812,
   
 },
 {
     "id": 8,
     "parentId": 6,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "Scandinavia",
     "field2": 3742748.296602,
 },
 {
     "id": 9,
     "parentId": null,
     "typeId": 0,
     "field0": "World",
     "field2": 44120885.587924,
 },
 {
     "id": 10,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1001",
     "field2": 3985.331955,
     
 },
 {
     "id": 28,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08634",
     "field2": 10307.142591,
    
 },
 {
     "id": 29,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08639",
     "field2": 17116.371459,
   
 },     
 {
     "id": 58,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0013",
     "field2": 19029.816578,
     
 },
 {
     "id": 59,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0031",
     "field2": -237.872707,
   
 },
 {
     "id": 60,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0034",
     "field2": 859.61482,
    
 },
 {
     "id": 61,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0037",
     "field2": 852.099758,
    
 },
 {
     "id": 62,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0043",
     "field2": 4452.369428,
    
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 63,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0046",
     "field2": -2226.184714,
     
 },
 {
     "id": 64,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0049",
     "field2": 6612.946972,
    
 },
 {
     "id": 65,
     "parentId": 0,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0050",
     "field2": 3844146.217229,
    
 },
 {
     "id": 66,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1002",
     "field2": 3985.331955,
     
 },
 {
     "id": 67,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1005",
     "field2": -2707.4266,
    
 },
 {
     "id": 68,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1008",
     "field2": -2436.68394,
     
 },
 {
     "id": 69,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1011",
     "field2": 683.959918,
   
 },
 {
     "id": 70,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1014",
     "field2": 54716.79346,
    
 },
 {
     "id": 71,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1017",
     "field2": 4027.155999,
    
 },
 {
     "id": 72,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "XCSW-0046",
     "field2": 604546.163294,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 498334.387729,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 73,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08655",
     "field2": 46191.801872,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 37131.473418,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 74,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CF-0012",
     "field2": 1845434.652127,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 1438283.786114,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 75,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CF-0017",
     "field2": 46486.869315,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 36285.674082,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 76,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CF-0002",
     "field2": -593582.845166,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -402546.0446,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 77,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1002",
     "field2": -73496.275293,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -5325.413593,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 78,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1005",
     "field2": 20670.748989,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 27954.103116,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 79,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1008",
     "field2": 53572.838484,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 27688.010937,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 80,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1011",
     "field2": 58.44961,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 83.488679,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 81,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1014",
     "field2": -296158.053382,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -288493.393334,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 82,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1017",
     "field2": -21563.217578,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -20779.990677,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 83,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "LOAN-0012",
     "field2": -16809.368436,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -16401.910829,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 84,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "LOAN-0017",
     "field2": 10307.142591,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 9867.818502,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 85,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FX-00342",
     "field2": 17116.371459,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 16382.149866,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 86,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FX-00354",
     "field2": 3721.762854,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 3541.481944,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 87,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FX-00406",
     "field2": 1479.737038,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 1408.059086,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 88,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FX-00410",
     "field2": 4699.141795,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 4487.080289,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 89,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FX-00418",
     "field2": 53.411383,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -25.478062,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 90,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FX-00426",
     "field2": 1625.14897,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 2319.189521,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 91,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FRA-0002",
     "field2": -4634.930756,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -6613.572492,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 92,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FRA-0005",
     "field2": -7375.479672,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -17104.920999,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 93,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FRA-0008",
     "field2": 0,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 0,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 94,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FRA-0011",
     "field2": 125.281197,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 181.176247,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 95,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "FRA-0014",
     "field2": 95.900079,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 122.515322,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 96,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0014",
     "field2": 35.094497,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 45.048084,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 97,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0017",
     "field2": 42.085388,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 61.758662,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 98,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0023",
     "field2": -1527.85633,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -7451.691034,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 99,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0029",
     "field2": -10505.835091,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -43600.76525,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 100,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0032",
     "field2": 0,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 0,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 101,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0035",
     "field2": 8.385045,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 2967.079788,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 102,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0041",
     "field2": 543.371559,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 29891.343594,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 103,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0044",
     "field2": 73.610827,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 5960.758206,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 104,
     "parentId": 1,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-0047",
     "field2": 894.247491,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 15292.150889,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 105,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1003",
     "field2": 3985.331955,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 20567.245997,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 106,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1006",
     "field2": -2707.4266,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -13972.313856,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 107,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1009",
     "field2": -2436.68394,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -12575.082471,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 108,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1012",
     "field2": 683.959918,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 3527.163486,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 109,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "BOND-1015",
     "field2": 54716.79346,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 282173.078874,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 110,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "XCSW-0004",
     "field2": 4027.155999,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 20767.938605,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 111,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "XCSW-0014",
     "field2": 604546.163294,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 498334.387729,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 112,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "XCSW-0017",
     "field2": 46191.801872,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 37131.473418,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 113,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "XCSW-0029",
     "field2": 1845434.652127,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 1438283.786114,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 114,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "XCSW-0034",
     "field2": 46486.869315,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 36285.674082,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 115,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "XCSW-0045",
     "field2": -593582.845166,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -402546.0446,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 116,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "XCSW-0053",
     "field2": -73496.275293,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -5325.413593,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 117,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "XCSW-0072",
     "field2": 20670.748989,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 27954.103116,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 118,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-00022",
     "field2": 53572.838484,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 27688.010937,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 119,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-00030",
     "field2": 58.44961,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 83.488679,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 120,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-00037",
     "field2": -296158.053382,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -288493.393334,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 121,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-00042",
     "field2": -21563.217578,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -20779.990677,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 122,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-04172",
     "field2": -16809.368436,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -16401.910829,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 123,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-04177",
     "field2": 10307.142591,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 9867.818502,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 124,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-04182",
     "field2": 17116.371459,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 16382.149866,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 125,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-04185",
     "field2": 3721.762854,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 3541.481944,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 126,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-04192",
     "field2": 1479.737038,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 1408.059086,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 127,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08627",
     "field2": 4699.141795,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 4487.080289,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 128,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08632",
     "field2": 53.411383,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -25.478062,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 129,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08637",
     "field2": 1625.14897,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 2319.189521,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 130,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08642",
     "field2": -4634.930756,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -6613.572492,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 131,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08647",
     "field2": -7375.479672,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -17104.920999,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 132,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08650",
     "field2": 0,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 0,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 133,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08652",
     "field2": 125.281197,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 181.176247,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 134,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "IRSW-08657",
     "field2": 95.900079,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 122.515322,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 135,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CF-0004",
     "field2": 35.094497,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 45.048084,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 136,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CF-0014",
     "field2": 42.085388,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 61.758662,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 137,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CF-0024",
     "field2": -1527.85633,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -7451.691034,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 138,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CF-0029",
     "field2": -10505.835091,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -43600.76525,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 139,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CF-0009",
     "field2": 0,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 0,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 140,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1003",
     "field2": 8.385045,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 2967.079788,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 141,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1006",
     "field2": 543.371559,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 29891.343594,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 142,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1009",
     "field2": 73.610827,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 5960.758206,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 143,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1012",
     "field2": 894.247491,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 15292.150889,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 144,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CRSW-1015",
     "field2": 1788.494983,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 30584.301778,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 145,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "LOAN-0004",
     "field2": 1788.494983,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 30584.301778,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 146,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "LOAN-0014",
     "field2": -1346.424043,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 2340.573474,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 147,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "LOAN-0029",
     "field2": -1349.527119,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 2335.6426,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 148,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CSA-3-1",
     "field2": 16116.217709,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 6028.837728,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 149,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CSA-5-1",
     "field2": -144675.967051,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -52043.568419,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 150,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CSA-10-1",
     "field2": 302407.68631,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": 109564.416581,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 151,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CSA-101-1",
     "field2": -189203.37048,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -69223.41632,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },
 {
     "id": 152,
     "parentId": 2,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "CSA-4-1",
     "field2": -955.127578,
     "node2": 2,
     "field3": -898.382846,
     "node3": 3,
     "field4": 1
 },     
 {
     "id": 230,
     "parentId": 4,
     "typeId": 1,
     "field0": "LOAN-0030",
     "field2": 4699.141795
 }
]
```

and the target data needs to have this nested array structure:

```js
[
       {
          "name": "HSVaR 1D 99%, By Location",
          "value":44120885.587924,
          "items":[
             {
                "name":"NorthAmerica",
                "value": 2297941.24812,
                "items":[
                   {
                      "name":"New York",
                      "value":2297941.24812
                   }
                ]
             },                
             {
                "name":"Europe",
                "value":31990486.243208,
                "items":[
                   {
                      "name":"London",
                      "value":5546919.06 
                   },
                   {
                      "name":"Paris",
                      "value":22700818.88167
                   },
                   {
                      "name":"Scandinavia",
                      "value":3742748.296602
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "name":"Middle East",
                "value":2959373,
                "items":[
                   {
                      "name":"Dubai",
                      "value":9832458.096596
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

*** UPDATE: FINAL WORKING VERSION - Same nested results as the gentleman who answered below with a non-recursive routine ***

```js
function parseTreeMapData(data) {
  // init new array, find root node
  var newJson = [];
  var root = _.findWhere(data, { parentId: null });

  // recurse data, starting with root node; pass in empty array   
  newJson = recurseTreeMapData(data, root, []);

  var top = [];
  top.push({ root.field0, value: root.field2, items: newJson.items });

  return top;
}
function recurseTreeMapData(data, root, newData) {
  // passing in the root node, get children, recurse until leaf is reached.
  var child = _.where(data, { parentId: root.id });
  if (child.length > 0) {
    if (!newData.items){
      newData.items = [];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++){      
      newData.items.push(
        {
          id: child[i].id,
          parentId: child[i].parentId,
          name: child[i].field0,
          value: child[i].field2
        });
      // recursve with current child record
      recurseTreeMapData(data, child[i], newData.items[i]);
    }
  }
  return newData;
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Bob

Comment: Why does it need to be recursive?

Comment: @MattR - perhaps it doesn't. However, I don't know how many nested levels I have in the "flat" version of the json file (i.e. the source file). That's why I assume it needs to be recursive. I would appreciate your input if you have a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your plunk and I think I've got the data right [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mJm68AVNVK9KEclcVXx?p=preview) although the treemap doesn't look right.

The algorithm I used was to first create a map from data IDs to data elements in the new format. Then I walk through the data again and add each data element to its parent's `items` array. Since these are all references we're mutating things in place and there's no need for topological sorting or anything.

I didn't find the need for recursion.

Comment: Yes, indeed your algorithm is much simpler than my recursive idea. And since `nodesById`,  `parent`, and `roots` all referenced the same object in the end, you only needed to return the `roots` array. Why do I always end up over-complicating things unnecessarily...

Comment: I ended up finishing my recursive version, anyhow. I wanted to prove to my self that I can achieve the same results.